# Make Teamviewer remember position, scaling, full screen

Tags: teamviewer

When I connect using Teamviewer, it starts with a scaling, and some arbitrary resolution. I always end-up changing it to Full Screen, 1366x768 (the resolution of my laptop), and full-screen.

Is there a setting that will make Teamviewer always start in this configuration, so I don't have to do it manually every time?

Comment: why not saving settings -->export and import whenever u use it?

Comment: What is that? I couldn't find an entry called "saving settings" anywhere in the menus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the remote PC to the Computers&Contacts list and set it to fullscreen on connect in the properties (advanced). You can also change the scaling or resolution that way.

Comment: It seems I need to create an account and give an email to be able to do so, though. I assume there's no way it could be avoided?

Comment: OK, I see they accept mailinator accounts.

Comment: I added the computer to my list but how do i access the advanced properties?

Comment: Right click the computer, click on the little wheel icon in the top right corner, select properties, click on Advanced.

Comment: This is not a good idea to use mailinator there. (it's not a good idea to use teamviewer in first place)

Answer (score 2):

I am using Teamviewer 11.0.53254. I had the same problem. I tried Maurice Gilden's  answer and  I still couldn't get it full screen.

I then set the remote computer's screen to maximum resolution and changed my monitor to the same resolution and then I got full screen.

Comment: i posted an answer here  as Jay/byteotech  and 
somehow it got highlited and won`t let make the changes to it.This is my first time here i edited as a guest then did the full registration when i tried to edit it  and got to a page about rollbacks is it possible to edit it
correctly and remove all the roll backs  i tried to contact superuser but everytime i send them a message it comes back as undeliverable can someone who knows how to use this please contact me byteotech@yahoo.com Thanks Jay  PS this comment i can edit no problem

Comment: Try the contact us link at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps.

1. Go to the **Computer and Contact**
2. You will get the ***Recent Connections*** Click on it
3. You will get to see a ***Gear Icon*** on the Top Right Side. After clicking on it, 2 more option will be visible, ***Delete*** and ***Properties***
4. Click on ***Properties***
5. Expand +***Advanced***
6. In the ***View Setting*** change the ***Remote Resolution*** with your desired Resolution.

Answer (score 0):

From your Tablet or other remote controler, go directly to configuration, then open Screen Resolution, set up as no change and that is it!