# Need a TeamViewer command line switch to start session in full screen mode

Tags: command-line, teamviewer, fullscreen, command-line-arguments

There's an official TeamViewer Help page that provides a couple of startup switches to create a shortcut to a particular host: https://www.teamviewer.com/hi/help/91-gibt-es-aufrufparameter-fuer-teamviewer

But, it does start in windowed mode, ignoring previously defined host settings. So far so good, the question is: what is the command line parameter to start session in full screen? Full list of such switches won't hurt either.

Update: This IS different from the saved host settings in TeamViewer app - I know pretty nice about that feature, but my question is about **opening connection via command line** (or shortcut) with specified parameters, since saved settings for host are ignored while opening connection via command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Teamviewer remember position, scaling, full screen](http://superuser.com/questions/639102/make-teamviewer-remember-position-scaling-full-screen)

Comment: @DavidPostill please see my update - my question is different, since it's related to command line switches.